# angular animate function expected error in ie9

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-9, angularjs-animation

I am using angular-animate.js in angularjs ui grid plugin. But in ie9 I am getting error "Function expected" in  function fireDoneCallbackAsync(). Please see the attached screenshot. How can I handle this error and also I am not clear from which part of the code this error is being thrown. 
[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

Although most modern browsers have good support for CSS transitions and CSS animations, **IE9 and earlier do not**.

If you want animations that are backwards-compatible with older browsers, consider using JavaScript-based animations.

[Described here in detail](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_12).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to having different version of angular js and animate js. My animate js was 1.2.26, recently I update angular js to 1.3.15, that resulted this error.  After updating animate js also to 1.3.15 has solved the problem.